# How to import Python modules for user in Jinja2 template

Tags: datetime, jinja2, ansible

I want to create a file name by formatting `datetime.now()`.  It is simple enough in Python, but the `datetime` module needs to be imported. How can I import it for use in a Jinja2 template?

For example, in this Ansible task:

```
  - name: myTask
    shell: echo "123" > /tmp/{{datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")}}.zaz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible already knows about the date/time.

```
 - name: myTask
   shell: echo "123" > /tmp/{{ ansible_date_time.date }}_{{ ansible_date_time.hour }}-{{ ansible_date_time.minute }}-{{ ansible_date_time.second }}.zaz
```

See [this page](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#information-discovered-from-systems-facts) for a list of default systems facts.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted the answer because it is a solution to my problem. I'd like to know how to use a python module within a jinja expression. Perhaps there is no other way than to upload a python script and execute it.